как сделать масштабирование изображения с помощью колёсика мыши в позицию где находится мышка
вот что у меня есть на данный момент но оно вообще не работает и как сделать приближение изображения как это сделано в других растровых редакторах таких как paint.net у меня идей вообще нету надеюсь кто ни будь сможет помочь.
Хотелось бы узнать как сделать приближение и отдаление от изображения и что бы появлялись полосы прокрутки что бы можно было перемещаться или перемещаться с помощью зажатой левой кнопки мыши+ctrl.
   using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
    using System.Drawing.Imaging;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    
    namespace ArtEdit
    {
        public partial class ArtEdit : Form
        {
            public ArtEdit()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                pictureBox1.Paint += pictureBox1_Paint;
                pictureBox1.MouseMove += pictureBox1_MouseMove;
                pictureBox1.MouseUp += PictureBox_MouseUp;
                pictureBox1.MouseDown += PictureBox_MouseDown;
                pictureBox1.MouseWheel += pictureBox1_MouseWheel;
    
                SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
                SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
    
                this.Width = 1600;
                this.Height = 850;
                var bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
                pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
                g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
                g.Clear(Color.White);
    
                // Пример инициализации переменной DrawPlace
                DrawPlace = new int[Width, Height, 3]; // 3 - для хранения значений R, G, B
    
                // новое
                // Настраиваем AutoScroll для формы
                this.AutoScroll = true;
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    
            }
    
            #region Variables
            // Int
            int penWidth; // размер инструментов рисования
            private int newWidth;  // Новая ширина изображения
            private int newHeight; // Новая высота изображения
            private int Height2; // Высота изображения
            private int Width2; // Ширина изображения
            private int[,,] DrawPlace; // Массив для хранения пикселей изображения
            private int ClickNum = 1;
            private int DrawIndex = -1;
            // Bool
            private bool active_drawing = false;
            private bool isMouseDown = false;
            // Point
            private Point mouseOffset;
            Point orig;
            // List
            private List<Entities.Line> lines = new List<Entities.Line>();
            private List<Entities.Point> points = new List<Entities.Point>();
            private List<Entities.Circle> circles = new List<Entities.Circle>();
            private List<Entities.Ellipse> ellipses = new List<Entities.Ellipse>();
            // Vector
            private Vector firstPoint;
            private Vector secondPoint;
            private Vector currentPosition;
            // 
            public static Bitmap image;
            public static string full_name_of_image = "\0";
            public static UInt32[,] pixel;
            // float
            private float Xscroll;
            private float Yscroll;
            private float ScaleFactor = 1.0f;
            private float x1,x2,y1,y2;  
            //
            bool paint = false;
            Point px, py;
            int index = -1;
            Pen erase = new Pen(Color.White, 10); //стерка
            int x, y, sX,sY, cX, cY;
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
            //PictureBox
            private PictureBox pictureBox;
            //Graphics
            Graphics g;
            #endregion
    
            #region Открытие ToolStripMenuItem
            private void открытьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                OpenFileDialog open_dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
                open_dialog.Filter = "Image Files(*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                if (open_dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ClearDrawings();
    
                        full_name_of_image = open_dialog.FileName;
                        image = new Bitmap(open_dialog.FileName);
                        this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom; // это я закоментировал
                        pictureBox1.Size = GetZoomedSize(image.Size, pictureBox1.ClientSize);
                        pictureBox1.Image = image;
                        CenterPictureBox();
                        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    
                        // инициализация графического обьекта
                        g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
    
                        // Получение матрицы с пикселями
                        pixel = new UInt32[image.Height, image.Width];
                        for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
                            for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
                                pixel[y, x] = (UInt32)(image.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb());
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        full_name_of_image = "\0";
                        DialogResult rezult = MessageBox.Show("Невозможно открыть выбранный файл",
                            "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                }
            }
    
            private Size GetZoomedSize(Size imageSize, Size pictureBoxSize)
            {
                Size resultSize = imageSize;
                float ratioX = (float)pictureBoxSize.Width / imageSize.Width;
                float ratioY = (float)pictureBoxSize.Height / imageSize.Height;
                float ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);
    
                resultSize.Width = (int)(imageSize.Width * ratio);
                resultSize.Height = (int)(imageSize.Height * ratio);
    
                return resultSize;
            }
    
            private void CenterPictureBox()
            {
                if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
                {
                    // Центрируем PictureBox относительно panel1
                    pictureBox1.Location = new Point(
                        (panel2.ClientSize.Width - pictureBox1.Width) / 2,
                        (panel2.ClientSize.Height - pictureBox1.Height) / 2
                    );
    
                    // Убедитесь, что PictureBox не выходит за пределы panel1
                    if (pictureBox1.Left < 0) pictureBox1.Left = 0;
                    if (pictureBox1.Top < 0) pictureBox1.Top = 0;
                }
            }
            #endregion
    
            #region Сохранение ToolStripMenuItem
            private void сохранитьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
                {
                    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
                    saveFileDialog.Filter = "JPeg Image|*.jpg|Bitmap Image|*.bmp|Gif Image|*.gif|PNG Image|*.png";
                    saveFileDialog.Title = "Выберите путь для сохраенения изображения";
                    saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
    
                    if (saveFileDialog.FileName != "")
                    {
                        Bitmap newImage = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
                        using (System.IO.FileStream fs = (System.IO.FileStream)saveFileDialog.OpenFile())
                        {
                            switch (saveFileDialog.FilterIndex)
                            {
                                case 1:
                                    newImage.Save(fs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                                    break;
    
                                case 2:
                                    newImage.Save(fs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                                    break;
    
                                case 3:
                                    newImage.Save(fs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                                    break;
    
                                case 4:
                                    newImage.Save(fs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        MessageBox.Show("Изображение сохранено");
                    }
                }
            }
            #endregion
      #region MouseMove
     void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
     {
         coordinate.Text = string.Format("{0}, {1}", e.Location.X, e.Location.Y);
    
         if (paint && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
         {
             if (index == 1 || index == 2)
             {
                 if (e.X < 0 || e.Y < 0 || e.X >= pictureBox1.Width || e.Y >= pictureBox1.Height)
                     return; // Ограничение координат
    
                 px = e.Location;
                 Pen p = new Pen(index == 1 ? Color.Black : Color.White, penWidth);
                 Point scaledStart = TranslateZoomMousePosition(py.X, py.Y);
                 Point scaledEnd = TranslateZoomMousePosition(px.X, px.Y);
    
                 g.DrawLine(p, scaledStart, scaledEnd);
                 py = px;
                 pictureBox1.Refresh();
             }
    
             x = e.X;
             y = e.Y;
             pictureBox1.Invalidate(); // Вызов перерисовки для отображения текущей фигуры
         }
    
         x1 = e.Location.X;
         x2 = pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width - x1;
         y1 = e.Location.Y;
         y2 = pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height - y1;
    
         pictureBox1.Refresh();
    
     }
     #endregion " MouseWheel "
     private void pictureBox1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
     {
         float cx = pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width / 2.0f;
         float cy = pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height / 2.0f;
    
         float w = (x1 < cx) ? Math.Min(x1, x2) * 2.0f : Math.Max(x1, x2) * 2.0f;
         float h = (y1 < cy) ? Math.Max(y1, y2) * 2.0f : Math.Min(y1, y2) * 2.0f;
    
         float scale = (e.Delta < 0) ? 1 / 1.25f : 1.25f;
    
         ScaleFactor *= scale;
    
         float width = w * scale;
         float height = h * scale;
    
         float wl = (w - width) / 2;
         float hl = (h - height) / 2;
    
         Xscroll = Xscroll * scale - Pixel_To_Mn(wl);
         Yscroll = Yscroll * scale - Pixel_To_Mn(hl);
    
         /*SetScrollBarValues();*/
         pictureBox1.Invalidate();
     }
    private float Pixel_To_Mn(float pixel)
    {
        return pixel * 25.4f / DPI;
    }


Попробуйте положить пикчер бокс в какойнибудь лэйаут и применить к нему layouttransfromcontrol.scaletransform и внутри подставлять значения для scaleX,scaleY. И использовать метод MouseWheel. А чтобы узнать координаты мыши можно использовать метод MouseHover
